# TryParse in a Sql Server computed column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, calculated-columns

I need add a computed column to an SQL Server datatable to perfomrs a cast over another column in same table. Is there the best approach to achieve it or someone has a better idea?

Important note: StringValue column has a 5% or less of non numeric values, they must be parsed as zero.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Tabla ADD
    ParsedValue AS case isnumeric(StringValue) when 1 then cast(StringValue as decimal(18,4)) else 0 end PERSISTED 
GO
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: It's SQL Server 2012, I'm not sure what edition it will be yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On SQL Server 2012 you can use [`TRY_CONVERT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx).

This is [more reliable](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2011/01/13/isnumeric-broken-only-up-to-a-point/) than `isnumeric` for this purpose.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Tabla
  ADD ParsedValue AS ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(decimal(18, 4), StringValue), 0) PERSISTED
```

I would consider not making it `PERSISTED` and not wrapping it in `ISNULL` for non numeric values though.

Treating non numeric values as `0` rather than `NULL` will mean that, for example, `AVG` calculations are not correct.

It is not necessary to mark it as `PERSISTED` to create an index on this column.